# Error norm in maple

Tags: pde, maple

I have the function $cos(x+t)$; the following PDEs have $cos(x+t)$ as the analytical solution of them:

$$u_t = u_{xx} -\sin(x+t) + \cos(x+t) \\
u_x(0,t)=-\sin(t) \\
u_x(1,t)=-u(1,t)^4-\sin(1+t)+\cos^4(1+t)\\
u(x,0) = \cos(x)$$

$$ v_t = v_{xx} -\sin(x+t)+\cos(x+t) \\
v_x(0,t)=-\sin(t)\\
v_x(1,t)=-\sin(1+t) \\
v(x,0) = \cos(x)$$

Now I computed the error norm $\| E \| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{1/h} h\cdot | u_{numerical}(i*h)-\cos(i*h+t_{final})|^2 }$ for a set of values of spacestep $h$, the set is: $\{ 1/16 , 1/32 , 1/64 , 1/128 , 1/256 \}$.

Now the plots of $\log_{10} \| E \| $ vs $\log_{10} h$ have been plotted, and I also calcualted the slope of this linear squares fit, for the second PDE above the slope is approximately $2$ for $t_{final} =5$, but for the first PDE above the slope is approximately $0.15$, how did this difference came about?

I am adding the code below in maple 2015.

```
hvals:=[1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256]:
tval:=5:
dopd:= (x, y, hv, tv)->  rhs
                           ( pdsolve
                             ( x,
                               y,
                               numeric,
                               time = t,
                               range = 0 .. 1,
                               spacestep = hv,
                               timestep = hv,
                               errorest=true
                             ):-value
                                ( t=tv,
                                  output=listprocedure
                                )[3]
                           ):
  pdes:=[ diff(u(x, t), t) = diff(u(x, t), x, x)-sin(x+t)+cos(x+t),
          diff(v(x, t), t) = diff(v(x, t), x, x)-sin(x+t)+cos(x+t)
        ]
  bcs:= [ [ D[1](u)(0,t)=-sin(t),
            D[1](u)(1,t)=-sin(1+t),
            u(x,0)=cos(x)
          ],
          [ D[1](v)(0,t)=-sin(t),
            D[1](v)(1,t)=-v(1,t)^4-sin(1+t)+(cos(1+t))^4,
            v(x,0)=cos(x)
          ]
        ]:
  for p from 1 by 1 to numelems(hvals) do
      h:= hvals[p]:
      for k from 1 by 1 to 2 do
          sol[k]:= dopd( pdes[k], bcs[k], h, tval);
    od:
      E[p]:= sqrt
             ( h*add
                 ( (sol[2](j*h)-cos(j*h+tval))^2,
                   j=0..1/h
                 )
             ):
  od:
  printf( "\n\n      Step Value     Norm Value\n\n");
  seq( printf( " %12a,   %12a\n",
               hvals[j], E[j]
              ),
       j = 1..numelems(hvals)
     );
  pA:=Array(1..2):
  pA[1]:= plot( [ seq( [ hvals[j], E[j] ],
                       j=1..numelems(hvals)
                     )
                ],
                labels=["space\\timestep", "Norm"],
                labelfont=[times, bold, 16],
                labeldirections=[horizontal, vertical],
                title="Norm vs step (lin-lin)",
                titlefont=[times, bold, 20]
              ):
  pA[2]:= plot( [ seq( [ log10(hvals[j]), log10(E[j]) ],
                       j=1..numelems(hvals)
                     )
                ],
                labels=["space\\timestep", "Norm"],
                labelfont=[times, bold, 16],
                labeldirections=[horizontal, vertical],
                title="Norm vs step (log10-log10)",
                titlefont=[times, bold, 20]
             );
  plots:-display(pA);
with(CurveFitting):
LeastSquares([[log10(hvals[1]),log10(E[1])],[log10(hvals[2]),log10(E[2])],[log10(hvals[3]),log10(E[3])],[log10(hvals[4]),log10(E[4])],[log10(hvals[5]),log10(E[5])]],v);
```

By the comments that I got I am adding a txt file with the computed errors, a plot of the computed solution of the PDE by maple and an explanation of the default meothd being used by maple:

"The first mode of operation uses the default method, which is a centered implicit scheme, and is capable of finding solutions for higher order PDE or PDE systems. The PDE systems must be sufficiently close to a standard form for the method to find the numerical solution.
The default method uses a second order (in space and time) centered, implicit finite difference scheme to obtain the computed solution. The number of points in the stencil of the finite difference scheme is one greater than the order of each equation.
  Note: A first order accurate accurate boundary condition (the default) can be used for second order accurate method, and still provide a solution of second order accuracy. Use of boundary conditions with an order of accuracy that is too low degrades the accuracy of the solution, while use of boundary conditions with an order of accuracy that is too high may negatively impact the stability of the problem. For first and second order accurate methods, it is generally recommended to use one or two more boundary points than the differential order of the PDE in the space variable. For third and fourth order accurate methods it is generally recommended to use two or three more boundary points than the differential order of the PDE in the space variable.
  PDE that are greater than first order in time are solved by converting to an equivalent first order system. Note: The conversion to first order is the expected one, namely that for any dependent variables that are higher than first order, variables representing all lower order time derivatives, and corresponding equations, are appended to the system. This choice of additional variables may not always be desirable, particularly when error control is in use, so often better performance can be obtained by choosing the first order system yourself. For more information on this topic, see pdsolve/numeric/firstorder.
Requested values that do not lie on a mesh point are computed using a Lagrange interpolation that uses 4 space points and 3 time points. The time points are chosen (whenever possible) so that only one time value is larger than the requested time.
"

[image: computed solution for x=1 and between t=0 and t=1]

In the next file there's the txt file with the errors.
[txt file with errors computed](http://www.4shared.com/office/_vKiRORWce/the_computed_errors_for_all_th.html)

I hope you can help me Kirill or anyone else.

Thanks in advance.

P.S
I am adding the plot of the absolute value between the computed solution and the actual solution.

[image: difference plot]

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to answer it (without access to Maple). Convergence rate of 0.15 would usually indicate the equation is not actually being solved, possibly a programming error. But just knowing the number 0.15 is not enough to diagnose the problem. Could you add more information, please?

Comment: What else can I add? I can add the graph of log log.

Comment: At least: all the computed errors for all the different values of $h$ (not just the convergence rate), a plot of the computed solution, a plot of the difference between computed and true solutions, and an explanation of what numerical method is being used by Maple for solving the PDE (including how it handles the boundary conditions).

Comment: @Kirill for the moment I'll add the computed errors, the plot of the numerical solution and and an explanation from the help of maple which describes the default method in my original opening post; later on I'll add the plot of the difference between the numerical solution and the actual solution.

Comment: OK, @Kirill I added what I said that I'll add to the OP; I will later one add the plot of the difference; I hope you can in the mean time look at it and gather opinion on it.